# Add link after woocommerce product price

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I need to add some text after the price on the woocommerce single product pages. I know how to do this with this code

```
    add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_html', 'custom_price_message' );
    function custom_price_message( $price ) {
    $vat = ' (plus VAT)';
    return $price . $vat;
    }
```

But I need the text (plus VAT) to be a clickable link that sends the customer to one of my pages. How can I do this? Thank you for your help.

Comment: Write it as an `a` tag? `$vat = ' <a href="#link">(plus VAT)</a>';`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming I understand your question properly, you just need to do something like the following:

`$vat = ' <a href="#link">(plus VAT)</a>';`

`return $price . $vat;`